# Debugging pyethapp

Tags: pyethereum, pyethapp

I'm having some trouble debugging [pyethapp](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp). I have also asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527761/debugging-python-code-in-pycharm). I get an error in **file console_service.py** at line 38 (as of version pyethapp 1.2.2/linux2/py2.7.9):

```
@inputhook_manager.register('gevent')
class GeventInputHook(object):

    def __init__(self, manager):
        self.manager = manager

    def enable(self, app=None):
        """Enable event loop integration with gevent.
        Parameters
        ----------
        app : ignored
            Ignored, it's only a placeholder to keep the call signature of all
            gui activation methods consistent, which simplifies the logic of
            supporting magics.
        Notes
        -----
        This methods sets the PyOS_InputHook for gevent, which allows
        gevent greenlets to run in the background while interactively using
        IPython.
        """
        self.manager.set_inputhook(inputhook_gevent)
        self._current_gui = GUI_GEVENT
        return app

    def disable(self):
        """Disable event loop integration with gevent.
        This merely sets PyOS_InputHook to NULL.
        """
        self.manager.clear_inputhook()
```

at the first line. Commenting it out allows the code to run, but is it possible to avoid altering the code?

Comment: reading also the other question, did you try removing ipython3 and have just the 2 installed, on some distrib between the distrib packages and the pip installs it can be a mess

Comment: I'll do that and provide feedback (I know for sure I'm not using ipython3).